# Why does git commit fail with a sed error?

Tags: git

When executing git commit on a branch I get the following error regarding sed.

```
$ git commit -am "test"
sed: -e expression #1, char 12: unknown option to `s'
```

The error seems to be specific regarding a single branch. I tried other repositories to see if something is wrong with my local installation of git but everything works. Trying to create a new branch and committing there works as well, but somehow in this certain branch git fails to commit. Is there any way to fix this or do I need to create a new branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should check your `.git/hooks/` directory to see if there any specific hooks that are written to trigger this.

One way you can verify this is to run `git commit` with `-n` so that the hooks are bypassed. If it works, then you need to fix your hooks.

Comment: Thank you. That seems to have worked. I have a hook that prepends the branch name to the commit message and didn't even cross my mind that could be the cause. Now next to figure out why it only fails on this branch.

Comment: You should debug your script and make sure that even it fails, it does so with a useful message.